# mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword crashes my app

Tags: android, firebase

Trying to use firebase login with e-mail and password. For some reason it is crashing my app whenever I press login button. Problem is with `LogMeIn` method. If I delete `mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword` everything is fine.

```
package com.example.yunus.relichunter;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

/**
 * The main application activity which serves as a login page.
 * @author Andrei
 *
 */
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

    public login(){


    }

    public static final String MY_PREFS = "SharedPreferences";
    private EditText theUsername;
    private EditText thePassword;
    private Button loginButton;
    private Button registerButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        initControls();
    }


    private void initControls() {
        //Set the activity layout.
        theUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
        thePassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password);
        loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
        registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Register);


        //Create touch listeners for all buttons.
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(login.this, "logine bastin",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LogMeIn(v);












            }
        });

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Register(v);
            }
        });
    }





    private void LogMeIn(View v) {

        //Get the username and password
        String email = theUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = thePassword.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(login.this, email,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Succesfully logged in.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            //finish();
                            //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), createprofile.class);
                            //startActivity(i);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(login.this, "Cant login for some reason.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });





    }


    private void Register(View v)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), register.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }



}
```

I had this working 10 min ago but for some reason it's crashing now.

Comment: As you had it working and didn't change anything it might be one of those weird problems which solve themselves just by cleaning and re-building the project. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try and check if isSuccessful is true